# PHP object property declaration error

Tags: php

I'm having a bit of trouble defining a property in a PHP class I'm creating.

```
<?php
class news_parser {
    public $var1 = Array();
    function contents($parser, $data) {
        printf($data);
    }
    function start_tag($parser, $data, $attribs) {
        printf($data);
    }
    function end_tag($parser, $data) {
        printf($data);
    }
    function parse() {
        if(!$file = fopen("http://services.digg.com/2.0/story.getTopNews?type=rss&topic=technology", "r"))
            die("Error opening file");
        $data = fread($file, 80000);

        $xml_parser = xml_parser_create();
        xml_set_element_handler($xml_parser, array($this, "start_tag"), array($this, "end_tag"));
        xml_set_character_data_handler($xml_parser, array($this, "contents"));
        if(!xml_parse($xml_parser, $data, feof($fh)))
            die("Error on line " . xml_get_current_line_number($xml_parser));
        xml_parser_free($xml_parser);
        fclose($fh);
    }
}

$digg_parser = new news_parser();
$digg_parser->parse();
echo phpversion();

?>
```

Produces the following error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in /homepages/8/d335242830/htdocs/caseyflynn/php/display_formatted_RSS_feed.php on line 3
```

As far as I can tell I have the correct syntax. My server is running PHP 4.5. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My server is running PHP 4.5

This is your problem: PHP 4 doesn't know the `public` keyword - along with a heap of [other OOP features](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration5.oop.php).

As @konforce says, in the code you show, you can simply switch to using  the `var` keyword. But the best thing would really be to switch to PHP 5. PHP 4's time is really, really over.

Comment: You can replace `public` with `var`, but Pekka's advice still remains true.

Comment: Thanks guys, I normally work with PHP5 anyways but this is for a class and my professor has some odd reasons for sticking with PHP4 on his private web server.